# Panda Pivot Table: calculate percentage with respect to two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the percentage with respect to 2 columns in a dataframe. The data frame is:

```
df1.head()
     ssaname      ym  tch_block  call_drop  cell_name
0  AAAAAAAAA  201504          0         39        345
1  aaaaaaaaa  201505          2         48        291
2  bbbbbbbbb  201506          2         49        360
3  ccccccccc  201507          4         59        357
4  ddddddddd  201508         10         74        363
```

The percentage should be `tch_block*100/cell_name`
The command tried is:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1,index=['ssaname'],columns=['ym'],values=['tch_block','cell_drop'],aggfunc = lamdba x:x*100/'cell_name')
```

Comment: with respect to 2 columns? do you mean you want the percentage grouped by two columns? as such I understand your question as just compute the percentage:  `df1['percentage'] = 100*df1['tch_block'] /df1['cell_name']`

Comment: with out computing percentage column in dataframe, the same percentage cant be implemented at the time of pivoting using aggfunc

Comment: but why do you try a pivottable? what kind of group by do you want?

Comment: group by ssaname and columns by yearmonth (ym) the output i want is

Comment: ssaname   /ym  201504 201505 201506 201507
 AAAAAAAAA   0.2         0.3          0.4      0.5
aaaaaaaaa        0.5         0.2         4.8        2.91

Comment: it is completely non understandable. Can you mention the output you want in the question regarding the input (df1.head) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how a `pivot_table` applies here.

In a `pivot_table`:

1. If multiple rows in the DataFrame...
2. have identical data in the columns specified by the pivot_table's `index` arg...
3. the rows are aggregated into one row.

The `aggfunc` determines how to aggregate multiple rows into one row.

But your pivot table has one index, `ssname`, and your DataFrame has no duplicates in the ssname column, so there aren't multiple matching rows for the pivot table's index, so in the pivot_table no aggregation into one row will take place.  You can see that here:

```
d = {
    'ssaname' : pd.Series(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']),
    #'ym' : pd.Series(np.arange(201504, 201509) ),
    'tch_block' : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 3,]),
    'call_drop' : pd.Series([10, 10, 10, 30,]),
    #'cell_name' : pd.Series([345, 291, 360, 357, 363])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

result = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['ssaname'],
    values = ['tch_block', 'call_drop'],
)

print(result)

 --output:--
   call_drop ssaname  tch_block
0         10     aaa          1
1         10     bbb          1
2         10     ccc          1
3         30     ddd          3

         call_drop  tch_block
ssaname                      
aaa             10          1
bbb             10          1
ccc             10          1
ddd             30          3
```

Now look what happens if the specified index, `ssaname`, has duplicates:

```
d = {
    'ssaname' : pd.Series(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa']),
    #'ym' : pd.Series(np.arange(201504, 201509) ),
    'tch_block' : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 3,]),
    'call_drop' : pd.Series([10, 10, 10, 30,]),
    #'cell_name' : pd.Series([345, 291, 360, 357, 363])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

result = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['ssaname'],
    values = ['tch_block', 'call_drop'],
)

print(result)

--output:--
   call_drop ssaname  tch_block
0         10     aaa          1
1         10     bbb          1
2         10     ccc          1
3         30     aaa          3

         call_drop  tch_block
ssaname                      
aaa             20          2
bbb             10          1
ccc             10          1
```

Now, there's aggregation in the pivot_table's `aaa` row because there were two `aaa` rows in the original DataFrame:

```
       call_drop ssaname  tch_block
    0         10     aaa          1
    ...
    ...
    3         30     aaa          3
```

The multiple rows are aggregated vertically--in other words, the aggfunc operates up and down columns, not across a row:

```
       call_drop ssaname  tch_block
    0         10     aaa          1
              ^                   ^                  
              |                   |
           aggfunc            aggfunc
              |                   |            
              V                   V
    3         30     aaa          3
```

By default, a pivot_table aggregates multiple rows using `np.mean`, and the mean of 10 and 30 is 20, and the mean of 1 and 3 is 2, so you get the following line in the pivot_table:

```
         call_drop  tch_block
ssaname                      
aaa             20          2
```

You can specify a different aggregation function:

```
d = {
    'ssaname' : pd.Series(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa']),
    #'ym' : pd.Series(np.arange(201504, 201509) ),
    'tch_block' : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 3,]),
    'call_drop' : pd.Series([10, 10, 10, 30,]),
    #'cell_name' : pd.Series([345, 291, 360, 357, 363])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

result = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['ssaname'],
    values = ['tch_block', 'call_drop'],
    aggfunc = np.sum  #****HERE****
)

print(result)

--output:--
   call_drop ssaname  tch_block
0         10     aaa          1
1         10     bbb          1
2         10     ccc          1
3         30     aaa          3

         call_drop  tch_block
ssaname                      
aaa             40          4
bbb             10          1
ccc             10          1
```

But the `aggfunc` only applies to multiple rows in the DataFrame that match the index(s) you specify in the pivot_table.

Here is an example where the pivot_table specifies multiple columns for the index:

```
d = {
    'ssaname' : pd.Series(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'aaa']),
    #'ym' : pd.Series(np.arange(201504, 201509) ),
    'tch_block' : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 100]),
    'call_drop' : pd.Series([10, 10, 10, 30, 10]),
    #'cell_name' : pd.Series([345, 291, 360, 357, 363])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

result = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['ssaname', 'tch_block'],
    values = ['call_drop'],
    aggfunc = np.sum

)

print(result)

--output:--
   call_drop ssaname  tch_block
0         10     aaa          1
1         10     bbb          1
2         10     ccc          1
3         30     aaa          1
4         10     aaa        100
                   call_drop
ssaname tch_block           
aaa     1                 40
        100               10
bbb     1                 10
ccc     1                 10
```

In the original DataFrame, there are two rows whose values for the columns that are specified as the pivot_table's index, `ssaname` and `tch_block`, are the same; therefore their data is aggregated into one row opposite the index: `aaa  1`.  The output doesn't bother to list `aaa` twice, but the result is really:

```
ssaname tch_block           
aaa     1                 40
aaa     100               10
bbb     1                 10
ccc     1                 10
```